# axis orient / position with dimple.js

Tags: dimple.js

Is there a way to explicitly position/orient an axis using dimple.js? I know that the first x-axis is added to the bottom and the second is added to the top, so I can get the desired outcome like this:

```
var xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "dur");
xAxis.hidden = true;
xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "dur");
```

...but that seems a little hacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way around that. Here's the relevant code : https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/objects/chart/methods/draw.js#L123

Because `firstX` is local to the draw function there isn't a way you could override it within the context of the loop.

You could possibly duplicate the logic used to position the top axis : https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/objects/chart/methods/draw.js#L226

And then only add one axis (which would be positioned at the bottom), then manually move your axis after the drawing, like :

```
chart.draw();
chart.axes[0].shapes.attr('transform', ...);
```

But you would need to do this after every draw or else they'll be repositioned. The hack you have seems easiest.

You could open an enhancement ticket for this though : https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+is%3Aopen